# where to add socket.io in my node.js app

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So i have this basic node.js server running, now i want to add another layer to it with socket io. I can use socket io, the example [here](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) is pretty simple and works great. But my app is much bigger so I do this thing where i load a bunch of resources and then load this server module by calling start_app.

I know i cant put io.listen(app) on line 3 because my server hasn't started yet.

I need that functional dependency, so how do i add add socket.io to the mix?

```
var   app= require('http')      // all http requests go to onRequest
    , url= require('url')       // path info stuff
    , io = require('socket.io') // socket io  

function start_app(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname.replace("/","")

        route(handle, pathname, request, response)
}


app.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.PORT || 8888)
io.listen(app)
console.log(". http://localhost:8888 .")
}


exports.start_app = start_app;
```

my error:

```
...socket.io/lib/manager.js:104
server.on('error', function(err) {
     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code:

```
app.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.PORT || 8888)
io.listen(app)
```

Could you do it like below?

```
var createdServer = app.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.PORT || 8888);
io.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
      socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
  });
});
```

We need the actual created server so socket.io can listen to that. Then handle the `'connection'` event.

Comment: edit: i thought that worked, sorry a little pre-mature. That just throws the same error when a client connects "no method 'on' of..."

Comment: @MatUtter Is it still not working? Try looking at my edit. (handle the `on connection` socket event)

Answer (score 0):

changeing the first few lines of the server fixed it. 
I'm not 100% sure why this works but, I guess it makes sense that the server shouldn't start until this function is called, since its the entry into the main event loop of the app.

```
var   app // all http requests go to onRequest
    , url = require('url')      // path info stuff
    , sio = require('socket.io') // socket io

function start_app(route, handle) {
    app = require('http').createServer(onRequest)
    sio = require('socket.io').listen(app)
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8888)
```